# Concise control flow with multiple string or conditions

Tags: ruby

This code is long winded and looks ugly:

```
def translate(word)
  if word[0] == "a" || word[0] == "e" || \
     word[0] == "i" || word[0] == "o" || \
     word[0] == "u" || word[0] == "y")
    # move word[0] to the end
    tmp = word.chr
    word = word.reverse.chop.reverse.insert(-1, tmp)
  end
  # add "ay" to end of word
  word.insert(-1, "ay")
end
```

This kind of syntax makes sense to be but only checks "a":

```
def translate(word)
  if word[0] == ("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u" || "y")
    # move word[0] to the end
    tmp = word.chr
    word = word.reverse.chop.reverse.insert(-1, tmp)
  end
  # add "ay" to end of word
  word.insert(-1, "ay")
end
```

Is their a more compact way to do these multiple or's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this code doesn't work:

```
word[0] == ("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u" || "y")
```

...is that the result of the expression `("a" || "b" || ...)` is just `"a"`. In Ruby, boolean operators like `||` return the last operand evaluated. The `||` operator stops evaluating its operands as soon as it finds one that's "truthy" (i.e. the first one that isn't `false` or `nil`) and returns it. If neither operand is truthy, the last one evaluated—the second one—is still returned:

```
  nil || true  # => true
  nil || "a"   # => "a"
  nil || false # => false
false || nil   # => nil
  "a" || "e"   # => "a"
```

The expression `"a" || "e" || "i"` is equivalent to `("a" || "e") || "i"`. The first part evaluates to `"a"` (because `"a"` is truthy—`"e"` is never evaluated), which leaves `"a" || "i"`, which also evaluates to `"a"`, so, as you discovered, in the end what you're doing is just `word[0] == "a"`.

A tidy and idiomatic alternative to all of this is a simple regular expression:

```
if word =~ /^[aeiouy]/
  # ...
end
```

P.S. The rest of your code is a little odd.

First of all, if you want to append something to a string don't do `word.insert(-1, tmp)`. Just do `word << tmp`.

Second, `word.reverse.chop.reverse` is a really tortured way to remove the first character of a string. Just do `word.slice!(0, 1)`. This returns the removed character, which means moving the first character of a string to the end is as simple as `word << word.slice!(0, 1)`. These small changes give us the following code:

```
def translate(word)
  if word =~ /^[aeiouy]/
    # move the first character to the end
    word << word.slice!(0, 1)
  end
  word << "ay"
end
```

P.P.S. There's no need to use the line continuation character (`\`) in your code. When a line ends with `||` Ruby is smart enough to look at the next line for the rest of the expression.

Comment: Another way to shift the first letter would be `word.chars.rotate.join`, but I lean towards your solution. :-)

Comment: Fantastic response, thanks!  

I was digging through Rdoc to find an easier way to move the character but in the end reverse.chop.reverse was familiar. Trying to pass my tests then optimize my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if ['a','e','i','o','u'].include?(word[0])
```

This will check if `word[0]` matches any of the elements in the array or not.

Read the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) for more info.

Example:

```
2.1.2-perf :001 > ['a','e','i','o','u'].include?('a')
 => true
2.1.2-perf :002 > ['a','e','i','o','u'].include?('x')
 => false
```